# "Homepage" added to title tag on site using Yoast SEO WordPress plugin

Tags: seo, title, yoast

I am working on a site where the homepage title tag says:

> Homepage - Funds, De-risks Capital Projects & Reduce Carbon Emissions

However, the SEO title in the Yoast module is:

> Funds & De-risks Capital Projects to Reduce Carbon Emissions - [site]

Why is "Homepage -" being added?

Comment: Check the Yoast help section to check all the issues that can cause that https://yoast.com/help/my-seo-title-isnt-displayed-as-i-have-entered-it/